# How to make an Android app that detect only specific bluetooth devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am a beginner to android.I am designing an android application that may only detect some specific Bluetooth devices .Is it possible to make an android app that only detect specific Bluetooth devices that we had mentioned earlier in the code ?If it is possible, what will be the android code for this ?

Comment: You can follow google developer's guide for now. If you use Low Energy you can add filter to your scan for finding specific service or devices, otherwise you can discover all and filter yourself. If you have questions in implementation, we will surely help.

Comment: How can it should be filtered ?

Comment: Bluetooth Low Energy: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le
This `guide` will help you to know some basic `classes` you would need to implement `bluetooth low energy`. Later you can delve deeper into them. `BluetoothLeScanner` is one such class which can `startScan()` to find nearby devices. You can apply filters here.